# How to arrange object Propeties order same in Array using swift

Tags: arrays, swift, swift-dictionary

I am trying to prepare Json Object in Swift

```
[
    {
        "property1": val1,
        "property2": val2,
        "property3": val3
    },
    {
        "property1": val1,
        "property2": val2,
        "property3": val3
    },
    {
        "property1": val1,
        "property2": val2,
        "property3": val3
    }
]
```

But when seing request the objects order is changed for array

```
[
    {
        "property1": val1,
        "property2": val2,
        "property3": val3
    },
    {
        "property1": val1,
        "property3": val3,
        "property2": val2
    },
    {
        "property3": val3,
        "property2": val2,
        "property1": val1
    }
]
```

How can we change same order for object in Swift.

Comment: Dictionaries are unordered by definition. As the values are retrieved by key the order is irrelevant.

Comment: Why does it matter? Does the wrong order give you an error or something?

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is simply a container that can hold multiple data as key-value pair in an unordered way.
so your JSON object always will be unordered.

but You can get in order if you retrieve it with key-value pair.

```
   print(object["property1"])
   print(object["property2"])
   print(object["property3"])
```